# what is the correct routing table of openstack controller?

Tags: controller, routes, openstack

I can't seem to figure out what should be the routing table of an openstack controller with 2 interfaces to the SAME network, i tried several configurations, the only one working was to disable one interface, that's not what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.4.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.4.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Ignore 10.0.4.2 which is used for internet connectivity.  Following entry is needed for openstack to work. It is the routing for openstack management network. I assume your controller IP is 10.0.0.11 .

```
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```